# Unable to connect to Socket Server running on VPS!

Tags: linux, java, vps, socket

I Could need some help here...

I'm running a java socket server on a 64bit Linux VPS and listening on a port 5555 however my clients aren't able to connect to that port.
When I run a `netstat -anp` on the server it gives me local address of  `::ffff:127.0.0.1:5555`and foreign address of `:::*` and the state is `LISTEN`.

Is the `::ffff:`in the local address part causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That address is your localhost interface, not an external interface. I assume your clients are connecting from "outside" the server, correct? If so, you'll need to set your java app to listen on whatever IP address is assigned to an outward-facing interface.

Comment: Oh! so if the IP address is for instance 192.168.0.55 I should setup java for 192.168.0.55:5555 rather than 127.0.0.1:5555 right?

Comment: Yes, that should work. You should also verify that there are no iptables rules that may be blocking traffic to that IP/port.

Comment: Well I am a noob on linux but I will check on how to do that!

Comment: Well your suggestion worked for me! thanks a lot!! Luckily I didn't have to do up the iptables.